# How to disable query profling in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using [xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp) ([apache](/questions/tagged/apache) + [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)) on local Windows 10.  While performing a query in [phpmyadmin](/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin). I accidentally clicked the box for `profiling` and now all queries run with profiling.  How do I turn this setting off?

I have tried restarting the server and MySQL database, but the setting persists.

I did not find a setting for it in the my.ini.  Also checked the database settings in phpMyAdmin and did not find a setting for profiling.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It seems the problem was the profiling option only shows up after you perform a query.

[image]

Except, it won't show up if your query uses aggregates or joins.

[image]

I used a simple query and was finally able to disable profiling again.

Comment: This didnt work for me either. It churns, then, nothing. I actually finally fixed it by deleting my cookies, and reloaded the whole interface.

Answer (score 4):

On the page which shows the profiling, browse down and you will find an uncheck button for profiling. Just uncheck it and you are done.

[image]

Comment: You can include an image directly in your answer. That is generally preferred. I will make the edit for you to try to help. If possible, try to get a higher quality screenshot as this one is potato

Comment: My profiling result doesnt show any of that. Its just a table of numbers, and no buttons or checkboxes follow.

Answer (score 0):

at the page of the server open the (Browser) then at the middle of this page just un-check 
the profiling check pox

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please explain more and insert some screenshots... How could we find `the page of the server open the (Browser)`?

Comment: Couldnt find whatever this answer is suggesting.